# How to send datagram to other machines from one ip address to another ip address in java

Tags: java, networking, udp, inetaddress

I want to send some messages to other machines by using UDP protocol in Java. And I knew my ip address and the broadcast address it should advertise on. Like my ip address is 127.0.0.1, and the I the other address is 127.0.0.200. I want to broadcast the message to machines with addresses from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.200. How to implement this in Java?

And the range of ip address may be 127.0.0.1 to 127.1.4.80.

I am a beginner and I just know I should use InetAddress type to express the ip address. But I  don't know how to iterate all the InetAddress objects.

Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. A `DatagramSocket`.
2. Some data in a `byte[]` array.
3. A target address:port, expressed as an `InetSocketAddress`.
4. A `DatagramPacket`, created from the `byte[]` array and the target address.
5. `DatagramSocket.send()`.

You can't use 127. anything if you want to talk to other hosts. Those addresses are localhost-only.

Comment: does DatagramSocket.send() asynchronous?

Comment: No it *is* not asynchronous. If that's part of your requirement it should be stated in your question.